# vertically stack MySQL results in single query

Tags: mysql

How would I combine (stack vertically) the following 3 queries into **one query** that returns 100 rows, 50 rows from category 1, 25 from from category 2, 25 from category 3 all chosen randomly.  I tried UNION but didn't seem to work.

```
select * from table where category_id = 1 order by rand() limit 50;

select * from table where category_id = 2 order by rand() limit 25;

select * from table where category_id = 3 order by rand() limit 25;
```

Comment: A `UNION ALL` should work if you enclose each part in parens `(SELECT...) UNION ALL (SELECT...)...`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To apply `ORDER BY` or `LIMIT` to an individual `SELECT`, place the clause inside the parentheses that enclose the `SELECT`:

```
(select * from table where category_id = 1 order by rand() limit 50)
UNION ALL
(select * from table where category_id = 2 order by rand() limit 25)
UNION ALL
(select * from table where category_id = 3 order by rand() limit 25);
```

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is the [UNION ALL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) syntax (link is to MySQL documentation).

```
select * from table where category_id = 1 order by rand() limit 50
UNION ALL
select * from table where category_id = 2 order by rand() limit 25
UNION ALL
select * from table where category_id = 3 order by rand() limit 25;
```

edit: Semicolons removed, thanks @Matt Fenwick

Comment: when I take out the semicolons, i just get 25 rows all from category_id = 1